# C++ char pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have a

```
*(char *) &data;
```

but need to send it as

```
(char *) &data;
```

Is there a difference between the two?

Added

---

Sorry for the confusion. I have two applications, first application in C that gives me *(char *) &data. On the receiving end (send over UDP) the C++ application expects the data as (char *) &data. I wanted to clarify if both the notion means the same or different

---

Comment: What do you mean you need to send it?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean with "I have a" and "need to send it". The question is rather confusing as it stands.

Comment: if I understood right, you need to get pointer `char* data_to_send = &data` and send it

Comment: -1 to counter upvote. this is not a good question. it is at best a confused one.

Comment: The two notations mean essentailly the same thing in C and C++. So if you are asking whether there some difference in C and C++ which explains the different notations in your two programs, then the answer is no. Your question itself is confused, suggest you post some of the code in question to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. There is a difference. The type of first expression is `char&` <sup>1</sup>. The type of second expression is `char*`.

<sup>1. Thanks to Pete for the explanation why its `char&`, not `char`. Read the comments.</sup>

Comment: The first is of type `char &`

Comment: @Novelocrat: Why? And how can you prove that? :-/ I tried it : http://ideone.com/idmIo ... but it doesn't show so!

Comment: It's a reference because assigning to the dereferenced pointer modifies the pointed to value.  If it was char it would be a temporary copy.

Comment: @Pete: Now I'm convinced. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have two applications, first application in C that gives me *(char *) &data. On the receiving end (send over UDP) the C++ application expects the data as (char *) &data. I wanted to clarify if both the notion means the same or different.

Comment: @Pete But doesn't that depend on what we assign it to? Assigning the expression to `char x` will only create a copy, so only `char& x` would work. Don't really see how that's different from directly assigning it.

Answer (score 2):

```
&data
```

This will provide the address of data variable. The pointer points to a chunk of memory location allocated to data.

```
(char *) &data
```

We then type cast the pointer to a character pointer - Effectively now the data is being interpreted as a stream of characters (1 byte at a time). So, still in memory it is the same address location, just that we want to interpret this memory chunk in a different way by typecasting. Finally,

```
*(char *) &data
```

gives you back the value at the memory location pointed by the pointer we got from above - that is the first byte of the memory.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like very convoluted code.

As mentioned already, the first expression evaluates to a char& (editable reference to char) and the 2nd to a char*.

The first is a de-referenced pointer to a reference to a char. The second is a pointer to a reference to a char.  Both seem like silly ways to be passing char data around to me.  If you need to send an updatable reference, send `&data` which will be a pointer to your `char data`.  If by send you mean pass into a method, you could also define the method as something like

```
void foo(char& inData) { ... }
```

in which case you could call

```
foo(data);
```

and the parameter inData inside of foo will be updated since it is a reference.  Another option is

```
void foo(char* data) { ... }
```

in which case you would call

```
foo(&data);
```

This is a more pure C style approach, but I still use it fairly often in C++ because I find it more obvious that you're dealing with a reference to an object when it's explicitly declared as a pointer.

I'm not sure why you'd want to be dealing with things like `*(char *) &data`, and I'd venture to say it'd be bad practice to use that in your code since it makes your code less readable.

For more info on references and a comparison to pointers see here
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html